# How different values of .. affect/affects?

Tags: grammaticality

May I know which one is grammatical?

> We will investigate on how different values of V affects the behaviour of the program.

> We will investigate on how different values of V affect the behaviour of the program.

Comment: william, it is not good or necessary, to mix American and English spellings in the same text. You should use one kind of spelling or the other, unless you include a name which uses just one kind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given that "different values of *V*" is plural (regardless of the plurality of _V itself), you would use *affect*.

> We will investigate how different values of *V* affect the behaviour of the program.

Notice that I've removed *on* as that is *not* grammatically correct.

Another example could be the following one.

> Seven breeds of dog are on show here today.